# Combinations of Strings, Not Characters

Tags: combinations

Can you show me how to get all possible combinations of three strings: `Al, Bob, Charlie`?

So that output would look like: `Al+Bob+Charlie`, `Al+Bob`, `Al+Charlie`, `Bob+Charlie`, etc?

I know how to do combinations of characters but don't know how it translates to strings.

Edit: There is a c# code to do recursive permutations here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37215/Permutations-in-C-Using-Recursion. And I've found similar for other languages. Butall those deal with characers. Where do I start?

And here is one from a book I read(in python):

```
def anagrams(s):
     if s == "":
          return [s]
     else:
          ans = []
          for w in anagrams(s[1:1]):
               for pos in range(len(w)+1):
                    ans.append(w[:pos]+s[0]+w[pos:])
         return ans
```

I understand recursion needs a base case.

Edit 2: I've got an answer but I'm not learning how it works, I'm looking for something that can be applied in most languages without having to depend on knowing the modules.

Edit 3: Current answer gives me blank output. So not working.

Comment: Show how you would do it with characters and someone will help you amend that for strings.

Comment: why did you downvote before giving me a chance to edit and provide what you requested?

Comment: That wasn't me - there, let me upvote that for you :)

Comment: my apologies. some people can be so uptight

Comment: Would that matter at all if they deal only with letters or numbers? You could create a dictionary with letter is the key and string as the value. From there on, once you have the combination/permutation of letters you could simply lookup corresponding string or any object you like.
And if you would ever use combination/permutation to a given level, over and over again, you could do that once and keep the result in a database, using (C,3,5 etc) as group filter values.

Comment: @CetinBasoz What if the number of strings exceeds the characters a-z, it wouldn't work that way if i understand you correctly. also do you mean figure out all my combinations before hand and put them in a db to fetch and the user knows no difference?

Comment: Letters meant to be symbols, need not be literally letters in the range a-z. Virtually it is an infinite set that you can use. To keep it simple at character level, you have 255 characters set, setting ASCII char 0 aside.
Yes, putting into a database is an option depending on your needs. Just like PI value it is a constant after all to a given depth that you can calculate beforehand, instead of calculating on demand, Then all you would do is to retrieve the ones that match to your requested set and map to your strings (which could be done all in SQL).

Answer (score 0):

As always in cases like this [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html) is your friend:

```
import itertools

def all_combinations(items):
    for length in range(1, len(items) + 1):
        for combination in itertools.permutations(items, length):
            yield combination

list(all_combinations(['Al', 'Bob', 'Mike']))
# Output:
# [('Al',), ('Bob',), ('Mike',), ('Al', 'Bob'), ('Al', 'Mike'), ('Bob', 'Al'), ('Bob', 'Mike'), ('Mike', 'Al'), ('Mike', 'Bob'), ('Al', 'Bob', 'Mike'), ('Al', 'Mike', 'Bob'), ('Bob', 'Al', 'Mike'), ('Bob', 'Mike', 'Al'), ('Mike', 'Al', 'Bob'), ('Mike', 'Bob', 'Al')]
```

This function is a [generator](https://docs.python.org/3.4/glossary.html#term-generator) that returns all possible combinations without repeating elements.

Comment: That is very concise and good!  Upvoted. But I was looking for a way to do it without importing anything in order to try it in other languages, although python is great its not useful for creating mobile apps or C languages for me.

Comment: I should add that im trying to learn the languages and dont want to depend on modules.

Comment: Thanks. The algorithm used in `itertools.combinations` is included in full in the docs I linked above.

Comment: Re: Depending on modules: It's certainly useful to know how algorithms work but for day-to-day work it's absolutely essential to know your language's standard library (and also the top 3rd party ones). Otherwise you'll be constantly re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: Thanks for the tip but wish there was pseudo code for this. When looking at the combination, i cant 'learn' how your getting combinations of strings and not characters. You accomplished it so eloquently though.

Comment: Actually, I tried running this code and get blank line as output.

Comment: My example was supposed to be run in the interactive interpreter. If you run it as a script you need to wrap the last line with `print(...)`. Or output the list in some other way.

Comment: I tried using print on it and it still gives a blank output.